Postgresql random value for each row for mass update
I'm using following query in Postgresql to update my users table. The goal is having random gender for each user, but at the end, it sets all users to one of male or female value.
UPDATE users
SET gender = (SELECT (array['male', 'female'])[floor(random() * 2) + 1])
WHERE id > 0;

Why this query acts like this? and how can I fix it?
I've already tried:
UPDATE users
SET gender = (
    SELECT (array['male', 'female'])[floor(random() * 2) + 1]
    FROM generate_series(1, 1)
)
WHERE id > 0;

but same result !

can you please provide a simple dbfidlle with some rows. the select is only run once

I think the problem is that your subquery only runs one, try this one
UPDATE users SET gender = (array['male', 'female'])[floor(random() * 2) + 1] WHERE id > 0;

FROM generate_series(1, 1) what is the point of this line, it only generates one row anyway? Why do you even need a subquery?

sub-selects, unlike simple expressions, don't track volatility.  An un-correlated sub-select is only run once, even if it is volatile.
In your case, the sub-select seems to be totally pointless, so just remove it:
UPDATE users
SET gender = (array['male', 'female'])[floor(random() * 2) + 1]
WHERE id > 0;

If for some reason you had to use a sub-select, you could force it to be a correlated sub-select by mixing in a bit of the outer query in a trivial way:
UPDATE users
SET gender = (SELECT (array['male', 'female'])[floor(random() * 2) + 1 + id*0 ])
WHERE id > 0;

